# Como saber se o usuário já está logado em outro dispostivo?

Tags: android, parse.com

Tenho um aplicativo Android o qual se conecta a API do [Parse.com](http://parse.com), mas também poderia ser outra API RestFul a qual eu mesmo criei. A dúvida é como fazer controle de sessões em diferentes dispositivos?

Exemplo, um usuário só pode está logado em um único dispositivo em determinado tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Mateus, pelo que entendo do Parse não faz este tipo de controle de sessão para você. Posso estar enganado, mas as sessões do Parse são bastante limitadas e só recentemente eles incluíram o recurso de validade de sessões, para você ter uma idéia! Até alguns meses a sessão do usuário era eterna, permanecendo a mesma depois dele alterar a senha.

Uma solução seria criar o seu controle. Se o seu objetivo é manter os dados sincronizados em vários dispositivos um caminho seria registrar todos os devices do usuário e criar *flags* em seus registros informando o dispositivo que inseriu ou alterou o registro. Então através de um script no *CloudCode* você envia msg para os dispositivos que precisam ser sincronizados novamente.

Acho que este seria um caminho.

Comment: Realmente, busquei em outros forúms, e uma solução foi na tabela de instalações criar um campo para controlar se está ativo ou não a sessão.

Comment: Confesso que estou tendo tantos problemas com o REST e CloudCode do Parse que estou considerando abondar a solução e desenvolver a minha própria. Funciona muito bem para o básico, mas uma vez que você necessite de maior controle a coisa vai se complicando bastante. Boa sorte por aí.